# Log4j2 - integer counter %i not resetting with time AND size rolling

Tags: log4j2, rollingfileappender

Using Log4j2 v2.18.0 I want to roll over the log file every hour **or** every 100 MB, so I'm using this:

```
<Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="APPLICATION" filePattern="/path/to/log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd.HH}.%i.log">
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy modulate="true" />
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100 MB" />
        </Policies>
    </RollingFile>
</Appenders>
```

When using both policies together, my expectation was that the `%i` integer counter would be relative to the time period (e.g., restart at 1 every hour), but instead it seems the integer counter keeps increasing. Is there a way to reset the counter or does it just increase forever until the JVM restarts?

What I expected:

- /path/to/log.2023-03-22.11.1.log
- /path/to/log.2023-03-22.12.1.log
- /path/to/log.2023-03-22.12.2.log

What I got:

- /path/to/log.2023-03-22.11.1.log
- /path/to/log.2023-03-22.12.2.log
- /path/to/log.2023-03-22.12.3.log

---

Based on https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#rollingfileappender this behavior appears to be a bug?

> A RollingFileAppender requires a TriggeringPolicy and a
> RolloverStrategy. The triggering policy determines if a rollover
> should be performed while the RolloverStrategy defines how the
> rollover should be done. If no RolloverStrategy is configured,
> RollingFileAppender will use the DefaultRolloverStrategy. Since
> log4j-2.5, a custom delete action can be configured in the
> DefaultRolloverStrategy to run at rollover. **Since 2.8 if no file name
> is configured then DirectWriteRolloverStrategy will be used** instead of
> DefaultRolloverStrategy.

> The DirectWriteRolloverStrategy causes log events to be written
> directly to files represented by the file pattern. With this strategy
> file renames are not performed. If the size-based triggering policy
> causes multiple files to be written during the specified time period
> they will be numbered **starting at one and continually incremented
> until a time-based rollover occurs**.

Comment: if remove TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy, it works ok. but if add multi triggers, the result is not expected (for example: CronTriggeringPolicy, TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy ...)